# how to redirect to 2 pages using a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, partial

I am currently using a partial to render a like/unlike button onto 2 different views:  a topics view, and a user_bookmarks view.  I do not know how to redirect to the topics view when the like/unlike button is clicked on the topics view pages and redirect to the user_bookmarks view when the like/unlike button is clicked there when the code for the like/unlike button is being pulled from a partial.

Here is my partial code:

```
<% show_remove_button ||= false %> 

<li><%= bookmark.url %></li>
 <div class="like">        
      <% if show_remove_button %>     
          <%= link_to "Remove", user_bookmark_path(get_user_bookmark_for(bookmark)), method: :delete %>
      <% else %>    
        <% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
          <%= link_to [bookmark, like], method: :delete do %><u>Unlike</u><% end %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to [bookmark, Like.new], method: :post do %><u>Like</u><% end %>
       <% end %> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my topics view:

```
<h1>All Bookmarks</h1>

<ul class="topics">
    <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
      <li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>
      <ul class="bookmarks">
        <%= render topic.bookmarks %>
      </ul>    
    <% end %>
</ul>
<br>
```

Here is my user_bookmarks view:

```
    <h1>My Bookmarks</h1>

    <ul class="topics">    
        <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
          <li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>
          <ul class="bookmarks">
            <% topic.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
              <%= render partial: "bookmarks/bookmark", object: bookmark, locals: {show_remove_button: true} %>
            <% end %>
          </ul>    
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    <br>

    <h1>My Likes</h1> 

    <ul class="topics">
        <% @liked_topics.each do |topic| %>
          <li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>
          <ul class="bookmarks">
             <% topic.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
              <%= render partial: "bookmarks/bookmark", object: bookmark, locals: {show_remove_button: false} %>
            <% end %>
          </ul>    
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    <br>

And here is my likes controller:

class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
     @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
     like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)

     if like.save
       flash[:notice] = "Liked bookmark"
       redirect_to topics_path
     else
       flash[:error] = "Unable to add like. Please try again."
      redirect_to topics_path
     end
  end

  def destroy
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
      like = current_user.likes.find(params[:id])

      if like.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Removed like."
        redirect_to topics_path
      else
        flash[:error] = "Unable to remove like. Please try again."
        redirect_to topics_path
     end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally learned a simple fix to my problem using `redirect_to :back`.  Here it is in my likes controller:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
     @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
     like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)

     if like.save
       flash[:notice] = "Liked bookmark"
       redirect_to :back
     else
       flash[:error] = "Unable to add like. Please try again."
      redirect_to :back
     end
  end

  def destroy
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
      like = current_user.likes.find(params[:id])

      if like.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Removed like."
        redirect_to :back
      else
        flash[:error] = "Unable to remove like. Please try again."
        redirect_to :back
     end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Good work.  Glad you figured it out.  I will take note of that trick for next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the question correctly you want to toggle the view that is rendered based off the view you are on.

You can use the following to return the path you came from.

```
redirect_to URI(request.referrer).path
```

request.referrer is a shortcut for *request.env['REQUEST_REFERRER']*

Assuming each view has its own path I would then compare the current path to decide what to do.

In your controller something like:

```
 if like.save
   flash[:notice] = "Liked bookmark"
 else
   flash[:error] = "Unable to add like. Please try again."
 end

 redirect_to URI(request.referrer).path
```

You'll notice i've also taken the redirect out of your if statement, as it is always the end point it can be stated after the block.  This is good practice for DRY code.

Alternatively you could set conditions ie.

```
redirect_to URI(request.referrer).path == topic_path ? topic_path : bookmark_path
```

If you havn't seen this before it is called a ternary operator.

```
condition ? do_this_if_true : do_this_if_false
```

In the context above imagine it like this:

```
if URI(request.referrer).path == topic_path
   topic_path
else
   bookmark_path
end
```

Comment: I tried putting redirect_to request.path == topic_path ? topic_path : user_bookmark_path after each block in my likes controller.  Now when I click like/unlike on either page it always redirects to the user_bookmarks path.  Did I misunderstand?  Do I need to put code anywhere else? Thanks again for any insight you can give!

Comment: Hmm, so the statement is always false. You want to redirect back to the same view you came from right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm wanting...any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Yea, try this: URI(request.referrer).path instead of request.path.   I may have my request variables back to front in my head.
Also you wont need the ternary operator if thats the case other than if you preferred it for readability ofcourse.  aka:  'redirect_to URI(request.referrer).path'  let me know if that works and i'll update my answer incase someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Ok I tried URI(request.referrer).path.  My User Bookmarks page functions like it should, but my Topics page still redirects me to the User Bookmarks page when I click the like/unlike button.  Any other thoughts?